# 1 merge conflict azure devops. How resolve?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge

I pulled request from branch **feat/02-authentication-azure-ad into develop** and had **1 merge conflict in package-lock.json file**. What is the reason for this conflict and how to resolve it? Help me please!!!

[image]

Comment: You and someone else edited the same file, check the file, correct the mistake (ask your fellow colleague if its good to him/her too), git add, git commit and problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

You could install this Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab&targetId=ca4e4e67-3099-4c62-9ea9-bef80e0cc70a&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList

[image]

This will allow you to review and modify the merge conflicts on the PR page.

[image]